# With 3 points, how do I calculate the offset of the plane they form

Tags: vector, geometry, plane

I have a triangle of 3 points A, B, and C.
I can find the normal of the triangle just fine by doing

```
|AB x AC|
```

In the below picture, it shows ABC that I know and |n1| which I can calculate. But how would I find P1?

[image]

If it helps, I need to use it to know if a Ray will collide with a Convex Mesh and it requires P1. Using A, B, or C, it seems to not work.

Comment: Is P1 perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: Do you mean the vector going from (0,0,0) to P1? Then yes

Comment: Your title is misleading. It does not correspond to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Vector `P1 = (D*a1 + D*b1 + D*c1)` should be perpendicular to vector `(P1-C)` (use any point from A,B,C), so dot product is zero

```
D * a1 * (D * a1 - cx) + D * b1 * (D * b1 - cy) + D * c1* (D * c1 - cz) = 0
or
D = (N.dot.C) / (a1^2 + b1^2 + c1^2)
```

If normal is unit (normalized), then expression for coefficient D becomes very simple

```
d = uN.dot.C
```

After that:

```
 P1 = D * N = d * uN
```

Quick check:

```
A = (2, 0, 0)
B = (2, 2, 0)
C = (2, 0, 2)
AB = (0, 2, 0)
AC = (0, 0, 2)
N = AB x AC = (4, 0, 0)
N.dot.N = 16
uN = (1, 0, 0)

N.dot.C = (4 * 2) = 8
D = N.dot.C / N.dot.N = 1/2
P1 = D * N  = (2, 0, 0)

d = uN.dot.C = (1 * 2) = 2
P1 = d * uN = (2, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't give P1, does it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Why? Compare with #13 here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Comment: you added the computation of P1 after my comment !

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, to make this clearer for you. Author's picture shows definition of vector `P1=(Da1,Db1,Dc1), that is why I used calculation of D coefficient

Comment: You are right, my bad. I'll do a fake edit to cancel my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation for any plane is

```
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
```

where `(A, B, C)` is a normal vector to the plane, that you have already calculated with three points.

To get `D` just substitute x,y,z with the coordinates of any point `(x1,y1,z1)` you know to be in the plane:

```
D = -(A*x1 + B*y1 + C*z1)
```

The good new is that if vector (A,B,C) is a unit vector, then `|D|` is the distance from the origin (perpendicular) to the plane.